# Ошибка 0 rows update when that should have been 1

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Используется
HeidiSQL.
MySql 5,7 х64

При добавлении(обновлении) записи в поле TINYINT (или INT).
Добавляются числа: 100, 150..

Появляется ошибка **"0 rows update when that should have been 1"**

```
CREATE TABLE `tst_001_tb_00` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `pl_1_txt` TEXT NULL,
    `update_pl_2` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pl_2_enum` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `update_pl_3` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pl_3_txt` TEXT NULL,
    `pl_tinyint` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pl_int` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Вопрос.**
В чём проблема?

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Mike Внёс изменения в таблицу: 1. переименовал поле `TINYINT` на `pl_tinyint` , а поле `INT` на `pl_int`. 2. Изменил длину  поля `pl_tinyint` с "10" на "4". Просто в таблице меняю цифру. А изменения не вносятся. Появляется сообщение об ошибке
см. скрин по ссылке http://prntscr.com/edkfn5
Причём ошибка выскакивает через раз. 
Один раз значение вводится, а потом выдаёт ошибку. 
Выполняя запрос через команду всё работает нормально см. скрин... http://prntscr.com/edkg5n.
В поле предполагается размещать цифры в указанном вами диапазоне.

Comment: @Mike Добавил `primary key`, всё заработало. Пока по крайне мере. Mike, оформляйте наверное как ответ...

Comment: @Mike Добавил, проверьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большинство сред разработки не могут обновлять данные в таблице, если не могут понять как уникально идентифицировать запись. В вашей таблице отсутствует первичный ключ (primary key) из за этого обновление и не проходит.